# Ratios of Gaussian integrals with a positive semidefinite matrix

Tags: definite-integrals, multiple-integral, positive-semidefinite, pseudoinverse, gaussian

Generally speaking, I’m wondering what the usual identities for Gaussian multiple integrals with a positive definite matrix become when the matrix is only positive semidefinite.
I could not find anything about this in the literature, any reference is welcome.

For instance, if ${\mathbf{A}}$ is positive definite, then we have

$\mathbb{E}{x_i} = \frac{{\int\limits_{\,{\mathbf{x}}} {{x_i}{e^{ - \frac{1}{2}{{\mathbf{x}}^{\mathbf{T}}}{\mathbf{Ax}} + {{\mathbf{J}}^{\mathbf{T}}}{\mathbf{x}}}}{\text{d}}{\mathbf{x}}} }}{{\int\limits_{\,{\mathbf{x}}} {{e^{ - \frac{1}{2}{{\mathbf{x}}^{\mathbf{T}}}{\mathbf{Ax}} + {{\mathbf{J}}^{\mathbf{T}}}{\mathbf{x}}}}{\text{d}}{\mathbf{x}}} }} = {\left( {{{\mathbf{A}}^{ - 1}}{\mathbf{J}}} \right)_i}$

If ${\mathbf{A}}$ is only positive semidefinite, do we have

$\mathbb{E}{x_i} = \frac{{\int\limits_{\,{\mathbf{x}}} {{x_i}{e^{ - \frac{1}{2}{{\mathbf{x}}^{\mathbf{T}}}{\mathbf{Ax}} + {{\mathbf{J}}^{\mathbf{T}}}{\mathbf{x}}}}{\text{d}}{\mathbf{x}}} }}{{\int\limits_{\,{\mathbf{x}}} {{e^{ - \frac{1}{2}{{\mathbf{x}}^{\mathbf{T}}}{\mathbf{Ax}} + {{\mathbf{J}}^{\mathbf{T}}}{\mathbf{x}}}}{\text{d}}{\mathbf{x}}} }} = {\left( {{{\mathbf{A}}^ + }{\mathbf{J}}} \right)_i}$

where ${{\mathbf{A}}^ + }$ is the Moore-Penrose pseudo-inverse of ${\mathbf{A}}$ ?

P.S. Of course, as pointed out by Gyu Eun below, both integrals become infinite with a psd matrix. But this does not imply that the ratio itself is infinite. The situation looks similar to Feynman path integrals in QM and QFT: we can talk only about ratios of path integrals since both integrals are infinite because they are infinite-dimensional. But the ratio is finite, otherwise path integrals would not exist. Hence my question is: do we have the same kind of infinity cancellation phenomenon with ratios of finite-dimensional Gaussian integrals with a psd matrix as with e.g. infinite-dimensional Gaussian path integrals with a non-singular operator?

The second formula with the pseudo-inverse holds with very high probability, that's an experimental fact. Indeed, when used in applications, it finally gives meaningful and useful results, everything works fine. It is possible that the formula holds only in special cases, including my own. But my own ${\mathbf{A}}$ and ${\mathbf{J}}$ are pretty random, so that the formula is likely to hold without conditions. But proving it under suitable conditions would be great too.

Comment: probably depends on the regularization scheme.

Comment: @user619894 May you be slightly more explicit please? Strictly speaking, there is no probability here, just integration.

Comment: The integral diverges, so you have to make sense of the ratio as a limit process, e.g. considering $A+\epsilon I$, integrating and then taking $\epsilon\rightarrow 0$. Different limits might produce different values.

Comment: @user619894 Ok, I get your point. I guess I should study path integrals because we basically face the same kind of regularization issue AFAIU. Moreover $\mathop {\lim }\limits_{\varepsilon  \to 0} {\left( {{\mathbf{A}} + \varepsilon {\mathbf{I}}} \right)^{ - 1}} \ne {{\mathbf{A}}^ + }$

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "The second formula with the pseudo-inverse holds with very high probability, that's an experimental fact." ? How do you compute the diverging integral to compare?

Comment: @user619894 I first developed a probabilistic code working with multivariate Gaussian distributions with pd covariance matrices. Then I realized that I need to work with psd covariances matrices. In this case the distributions are NOT absolutely continuous w.r.t. the Lebesgue measure but absolutely continuous w.r.t the restriction of the Lebesgue measure on the codomain, with covariance matrix given by the pseudo-inverse. So I just replaced 1) the dimension by the rank 2) the determinant by the pseudo-determinant and 3) the inverse by the pseudo-inverse everywhere in my calculations...

Comment: @user619894  This includes the formula above but many other formulae, e.g. block formulae for the determinant and the inverse (Schur complement). I know that block formulae for the pseudo-det et the pseudo-inverse work only under special algebraic conditions that are fulfilled in my own case because everything works at the end. So, perhaps there are some conditions for the formula above, but it basically works.

Comment: @user619894 I validated my code through computer simulations with ground truth. And it works, I get excellent estimates, just like in the pd/non-singular case. The probability to get correct results at the end with tons of wrong formulae on the way being being fairly negligible, the formula above holds with high probability, at least for my own A and J.

Comment: So, Monte-Carlo integration? How do you generate random variates in the singular ( = zero eigen value) direction? If you are projecting out these directions then the pseudoinverse, or the ridge regularization I proposed will give the same results, with the advantage of the p-i being that you get the projection automatically. In any case, this is not the same as trying to integrate over the entire space.

Comment: @user619894 No, no Monte-Carlo integration, nothing like that. The purpose of my code is to compute an estimate of some quantity of interest. So I generate data with known values of the quantity of interest and I check that my code estimates this quantity correctly... despite the fact that it relies on many unusual, generalized formulae that I cannot prove.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123512/discussion-between-fabrice-pautot-and-user619894).

Answer (score 1):

If $\mathbf{A}$ is only positive semidefinite, then the corresponding Gaussian integrals are not necessarily defined. In one dimension the only positive semidefinite matrix which is not positive definite is the zero matrix, and $x^t\mathbf{A}x = 0$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$, so
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^t\mathbf{A}x}~dx = \int_{-\infty}^\infty 1~dx = \infty.
$$
In higher dimensions the same holds for the same reasons. For instance the Gaussian integral with the matrix
$$
\mathbf{A} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0\\
0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
is infinite because you run into the same one-dimensional integral once you reduce to an iterated integral.

Comment: Yes, Gaussian integrals with a positive semidefinite matrix are basically infinite since we find the determinant at the denominator. But in my example, we have a ratio of two infinite Gaussian integrals. Hence the ratio can be finite. This is exactly the same situation as with Feynman path integrals in QM and QFT: we can only talk about the ratio of two path integrals, because each integral is infinite since it is infinite-dimensional. But the ratio is finite, otherwise path integrals would not exist...

Comment: Hence my question is: do we have the same cancellation phenomenon with ratios of Gaussian integrals with a psd matrix?

Comment: I edit my question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very partial answer.

**Theorem** : if ${\mathbf{A}}$  is positive semidefinite and ${\mathbf{J}} = {\mathbf{A}}{{\mathbf{A}}^ + }{\mathbf{J}}$, then $\mathbb{E}{\mathbf{x}} = {{\mathbf{A}}^ + }{\mathbf{J}}$ , provided we allow ourself to cancel out terms like $\frac{a}{a}$  even if $a$   is infinite.

**Proof** : recall one of the usual proofs of the identity

$\int\limits_{{\mathbb{R}^n}} {{e^{ - \frac{1}{2}{{\mathbf{x}}^{\mathbf{T}}}{\mathbf{Ax}} + {{\mathbf{J}}^T}{\mathbf{x}}}}{\text{d}}{\mathbf{x}}}  = \frac{{{{\left( {2\pi } \right)}^{\frac{n}{2}}}}}{{\sqrt {\left| {\mathbf{A}} \right|} }}{e^{\frac{1}{2}{{\mathbf{J}}^T}{{\mathbf{A}}^{ - 1}}{\mathbf{J}}}}$

for a positive definite matrix ${\mathbf{A}}$ .

Substitute ${\mathbf{x}}$ by  ${\mathbf{y}} = {\mathbf{x}} - {{\mathbf{A}}^{ - 1}}{\mathbf{J}}$

${{\text{d}}^n}{\mathbf{x}} = {{\text{d}}^n}{\mathbf{y}}$

$ - \frac{1}{2}{{\mathbf{x}}^T}{\mathbf{Ax}} + {{\mathbf{J}}^T}{\mathbf{x}} =  - \frac{1}{2}{\left( {{\mathbf{y}} + {{\mathbf{A}}^{ - 1}}{\mathbf{J}}} \right)^T}{\mathbf{A}}\left( {{\mathbf{y}} + {{\mathbf{A}}^{ - 1}}{\mathbf{J}}} \right) + {{\mathbf{J}}^T}\left( {{\mathbf{y}} + {{\mathbf{A}}^{ - 1}}{\mathbf{J}}} \right) =  \\
   - \frac{1}{2}\left( {{{\mathbf{J}}^T}{{\mathbf{A}}^{ - 1}}{\mathbf{J}} + {{\mathbf{J}}^T}{\mathbf{y}} + {{\mathbf{y}}^T}{\mathbf{J}} + {{\mathbf{y}}^T}{\mathbf{Ay}}} \right) + {{\mathbf{J}}^T}{{\mathbf{A}}^{ - 1}}{\mathbf{J}} + {{\mathbf{J}}^T}{\mathbf{y}} =  \\
  \frac{1}{2}{{\mathbf{J}}^T}{{\mathbf{A}}^{ - 1}}{\mathbf{J}} - \frac{1}{2}{{\mathbf{y}}^T}{\mathbf{Ay}} \\ $

Therefore

$\int\limits_{{\mathbb{R}^n}} {{e^{ - \frac{1}{2}{{\mathbf{x}}^T}{\mathbf{Ax}} + {{\mathbf{J}}^T}{\mathbf{x}}}}{\text{d}}{\mathbf{x}}}  = {e^{\frac{1}{2}{{\mathbf{J}}^T}{{\mathbf{A}}^{ - 1}}{\mathbf{J}}}}\int\limits_{{\mathbb{R}^n}} {{e^{ - \frac{1}{2}{{\mathbf{y}}^T}{\mathbf{Ay}}}}{\text{d}}{\mathbf{y}}}  = \frac{{{{\left( {2\pi } \right)}^{\frac{n}{2}}}}}{{\sqrt {\left| {\mathbf{A}} \right|} }}{e^{\frac{1}{2}{{\mathbf{J}}^T}{{\mathbf{A}}^{ - 1}}{\mathbf{J}}}}$

Then, by the Leibniz rule/Feynman trick

$ \frac{{\partial \int\limits_{{\mathbb{R}^n}} {{e^{ - \frac{1}{2}{{\mathbf{x}}^T}{\mathbf{Ax}} + {{\mathbf{J}}^T}{\mathbf{x}}}}{\text{d}}{\mathbf{x}}} }}{{\partial {{\mathbf{J}}_i}}} = \int\limits_{{\mathbb{R}^n}} {\frac{{\partial {e^{ - \frac{1}{2}{{\mathbf{x}}^T}{\mathbf{Ax}} + {{\mathbf{J}}^T}{\mathbf{x}}}}}}{{\partial {{\mathbf{J}}_i}}}{\text{d}}{\mathbf{x}}}  = \int\limits_{{\mathbb{R}^n}} {{x_i}{e^{ - \frac{1}{2}{{\mathbf{x}}^T}{\mathbf{Ax}} + {{\mathbf{J}}^T}{\mathbf{x}}}}{\text{d}}{\mathbf{x}}}  =  \\
  \frac{{{{\left( {2\pi } \right)}^{\frac{n}{2}}}}}{{\sqrt {\left| {\mathbf{A}} \right|} }}\frac{{\partial {e^{\frac{1}{2}{{\mathbf{J}}^T}{{\mathbf{A}}^{ - 1}}{\mathbf{J}}}}}}{{\partial {{\mathbf{J}}_i}}} = \frac{1}{2}\int\limits_{{\mathbb{R}^n}} {{e^{ - \frac{1}{2}{{\mathbf{x}}^T}{\mathbf{Ax}} + {{\mathbf{J}}^T}{\mathbf{x}}}}{\text{d}}{\mathbf{x}}} \frac{\partial }{{\partial {{\mathbf{J}}_i}}}{{\mathbf{J}}^T}{{\mathbf{A}}^{ - 1}}{\mathbf{J}}  \\  $

Hence

$\mathbb{E}{x_i} = \frac{{\int\limits_{\,{\mathbf{x}}} {{x_i}{e^{ - \frac{1}{2}{{\mathbf{x}}^T}{\mathbf{Ax}} + {{\mathbf{J}}^T}{\mathbf{x}}}}{\text{d}}{\mathbf{x}}} }}{{\int\limits_{\,{\mathbf{x}}} {{e^{ - \frac{1}{2}{{\mathbf{x}}^T}{\mathbf{Ax}} + {{\mathbf{J}}^T}{\mathbf{x}}}}{\text{d}}{\mathbf{x}}} }} = \frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial }{{\partial {{\mathbf{J}}_i}}}{{\mathbf{J}}^T}{{\mathbf{A}}^{ - 1}}{\mathbf{J}} = {\left( {{{\mathbf{A}}^{ - 1}}{\mathbf{J}}} \right)_i}$

Now, for a positive semidefinite matrix  ${\mathbf{A}}$, substitute ${\mathbf{x}}$ by  ${\mathbf{y}} = {\mathbf{x}} - {{\mathbf{A}}^ + }{\mathbf{J}}$

$   - \frac{1}{2}{{\mathbf{x}}^T}{\mathbf{Ax}} + {{\mathbf{J}}^T}{\mathbf{x}} =  - \frac{1}{2}{\left( {{\mathbf{y}} + {{\mathbf{A}}^ + }{\mathbf{J}}} \right)^T}{\mathbf{A}}\left( {{\mathbf{y}} + {{\mathbf{A}}^ + }{\mathbf{J}}} \right) + {{\mathbf{J}}^T}\left( {{\mathbf{y}} + {{\mathbf{A}}^ + }{\mathbf{J}}} \right) =  \\
   - \frac{1}{2}\left( {{{\mathbf{J}}^T}\underbrace {{{\mathbf{A}}^ + }{\mathbf{A}}{{\mathbf{A}}^ + }}_{{{\mathbf{A}}^ + }}{\mathbf{J}} + {{\mathbf{J}}^T}{{\mathbf{A}}^ + }{\mathbf{Ay}} + {{\mathbf{y}}^T}{\mathbf{A}}{{\mathbf{A}}^ + }{\mathbf{J}} + {{\mathbf{y}}^T}{\mathbf{Ay}}} \right) + {{\mathbf{J}}^T}{{\mathbf{A}}^ + }{\mathbf{J}} + {{\mathbf{J}}^T}{\mathbf{y}} = \\
  \frac{1}{2}{{\mathbf{J}}^T}{{\mathbf{A}}^ + }{\mathbf{J}} - \frac{1}{2}{{\mathbf{y}}^T}{\mathbf{Ay}} + {{\mathbf{J}}^T}\left( {{\mathbf{I}} - {{\mathbf{A}}^ + }{\mathbf{A}}} \right){\mathbf{y}} \\  $

The integral

$\int\limits_{\,{\mathbf{x}}} {{e^{ - \frac{1}{2}{{\mathbf{y}}^T}{\mathbf{Ay}}}}{\text{d}}{\mathbf{y}}} $

now is infinite. But it is not a big deal because it cancels out in the Leibniz rule/Feynman trick above (please tell me).

Therefore, the term ${{\mathbf{J}}^T}\left( {{\mathbf{I}} - {{\mathbf{A}}^ + }{\mathbf{A}}} \right){\mathbf{y}}$ , where ${\mathbf{I}} - {{\mathbf{A}}^ + }{\mathbf{A}}$  is the orthogonal projector on  $\ker {\mathbf{A}}$, is the main obstruction against the generalized formula.

So, if  ${{\mathbf{J}}^T}\left( {{\mathbf{I}} - {{\mathbf{A}}^ + }{\mathbf{A}}} \right) = 0 \Leftrightarrow {\mathbf{J}} = {\mathbf{A}}{{\mathbf{A}}^ + }{\mathbf{J}}$ then

$\int\limits_{{\mathbb{R}^n}} {{e^{ - \frac{1}{2}{{\mathbf{x}}^T}{\mathbf{Ax}} + {{\mathbf{J}}^T}{\mathbf{x}}}}{\text{d}}{\mathbf{x}}}  \propto {e^{\frac{1}{2}{{\mathbf{J}}^T}{{\mathbf{A}}^ + }{\mathbf{J}}}}$

and the generalized formula

$\mathbb{E}{\mathbf{x}} = {{\mathbf{A}}^ + }{\mathbf{J}}$

follows by the Leibniz rule/Feynman trick.

Perhaps this condition is fulfilled with my own ${\mathbf{A}}$  and ${\mathbf{J}}$, I need to check.

Comment: It occurred to me that while $A^{-1}$ is meaningless, if $J$ doesn't have any projection in the kernel of $A$, then $A^{-1}J$ can be given a meaning either by $\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0} (A+\epsilon I)^{-1}J$ or $A^+J$ and the results are identical.